# doc2vec infer words from vectors

Tags: doc2vec

I am clustering comments.

After preprocessing and a vectorization of a text, I have inferred vectors from my doc2vec model and applied kmeans.

After that I want to convert cluster centroid vectors to words to kinda look at the semantic cores of the clusters. Is it possible?

Edit: I use python/gensim.

Comment: The term 'doc2vec' is used to refer to several different algorithms/implementations. What language & library are you using?

Comment: I use python/gensim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of potential approaches you could try, and see which might offer what you want.

First & foremost, some of the Gensim `Doc2Vec` modes co-train word-vectors into the same coordinate system as the doc-vectors – allowing direct comparisons betwee words & docs, sometimes even to the level of compositional 'vector-arithmetic' (like in the famous word2vec analogy-solving examples).

You can see this potential discussed in the paper ["Document Embedding with Paragraph Vectors"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.07998).

The default PV-DM mode (parameter `dm=1`) automatically co-trains words and docs in the same space. You can also add interleaved word-vector skip-gram training into the other PV-DBOW `dm=0` mode by adding the optional parameter `dbow_words=1`.

While it is still the case that `d2v_model.dv.most_similar(docvec_or_doctag)` will only return doc-vector results, and `d2v_model.wv.most_similar(wordvec_or_word_token)` will only return word-vector results, you can absolutely provide a raw vector of a document to the set of word-vectors, or a word-vector to the set of doc-vectors, to get the nearest-neighbors of the other type.

So in one of these modes, with doc-vector, you can use...

```
d2v_model.wv.most_simlar(positive=[doc_vector])
```

...to get a list-of-words that are closest to that doc-vector. Whether they're sufficiently representative will vary based on lots of factors. (If they seem totally random, there may be other problems with your data-sufficiency or process, or you may be using the `dm=0, dbow_words=0` mode that leaves words random & untrained.)

You could use this on the centroid of your clusters – but note, a centroid might hide lots of the variety of a larger grouping, which might include docs *not* all in a tight 'ball' around the centroid. So you could also use this on *all* docs in a cluster, to get the top-N closest words to each – and then summarize the cluster as the words most often appearing in those many top-N lists, or most *uniquely* appearing in those top-N lists (versus the top-N lists of other clusters). That might describe more of the full cluster.

Separately, there's a method from Gensim's `Word2Vec`, [`predict_output_word()`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.predict_output_word), which vaguely simulates the word2vec training-predictions to give a ranked list of predictions of a word from its surrounding words. The same code *could* be generalized to predict document-words from a doc-vector – there's an [open pending issue to do so](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2459), and it'd be a simple bit of coding, though no-one's tackled it yet. (It'd be a welcome, and pretty easy, 1ast contribution to the Gensim project.)

Also: after having established your clusters, you could even put the `Doc2Vec` model aside, and use more traditional direct counting/frequency methods to pick out the most-salient words in each cluster. For example, turn each cluser into a single synthetic pseudodocument. Rank the words inside by TF-IDF, compared to the other cluster pseudodocs. (Or, get the top TF-IDF terms for every one of the individual original documents; describe each cluster by the most-often-relevant words tallied across all cluster docs.)

Answer (score 0):

Though gojomo's answer makes perfect sense, I've decided to go the other way around  with classification instead of clusterization. The article about the library I have found useful:

[https://towardsdatascience.com/unsupervised-text-classification-with-lbl2vec-6c5e040354de]](https://towardsdatascience.com/unsupervised-text-classification-with-lbl2vec-6c5e040354de%5D)